# Form always refreshes on submit even with preventing default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have seen this question arise many times and the common answer is to do `preventDefault()` or `return false` but neither have seemed to work for me. Could anyone show me what I may be missing here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".compareForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Calling compare endpoint");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/compare",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        product_url: $(".inputClass").val(),
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        if (window.location.href !== "./result.html") {
          window.location.href = "./result.html";
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, statusText) {
        console.log("There was an erorr");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-search">
    <form class="compareForm">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="border">
          <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="" placeholder="Paste the product URL here">
        </div>
        <button type="submit"> <span>Search</span><img src="./assets/images/icon-search.png" alt="Cartaygo"></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what else I need to do here. I've done something similar like this before and used this exact same layout and it works just fine (except this has more complicated css). But it still refreshes.

I can see the logs before the page refreshes so I know it's being called. I just need it to stop refreshing.

Comment: First thing to confirm: is your `$(".compareForm").submit(` definitely running - do you get the console.log?

Comment: Yes I can see the log briefly before it refreshes. I can even see success sometime before it refreshes

Comment: Are you sure it's actually reloading? You literally have `window.location.href = "./result.html"` which will immediately navigate to `result.html`. Are you sure that's not what's happening? FYI, you can enable an option called "Preserve log" for the _Console_ and _Network_ developer tools which may help you debug this

Comment: Yes, I should clarify --the results page also contains the same form so that a search can also be triggered from the results page. This code is specifically from the `results.html` and I have a check for if the form triggers from results page, so it shouldn't refresh when search is triggered from `results.html` unless my check is not doing what I think it is

Comment: So it works perfectly if you remove `window.location.href =` ?

Comment: Does the `window.location.href` *ever* equal `./page.html`?  Seems unlikely, normally it has the full path.

Comment: Your check is not doing what you think. I suggest you `console.log(window.location.href)`

Comment: Ah you all are correct. It's the check not doing what I think it's doing. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the **form is not refreshed** and the "`submit`" event is canceled. Instead, AJAX requests data and prints the error message because it cannot find the page.

It is probably a set of events happening elsewhere in the code that exhibits this behavior.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".compareForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Calling compare endpoint");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/compare",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        product_url: $(".inputClass").val(),
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        if (window.location.href !== "./result.html") {
          window.location.href = "./result.html";
        }
        if (data.amazonProducts == null) {
          $(".result-recommendation").html("Sorry, we could not find any comparable products to this.");
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, statusText) {
        console.log("There was an erorr");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-search">
    <form class="compareForm">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="border">
          <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="" placeholder="Paste the product URL here">
        </div>
        <button type="submit"> <span>Search</span><img src="./assets/images/icon-search.png" alt="Cartaygo"></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I understand from the comments, "`location.href`" takes you to a new page (even if it is the same), and you think the form element caused it.

Again, as far as I can deduce from your comments, "`data.amazonProducts`" data must not be "`null`" in order to exhibit this behavior. In this case, let's prepare a new snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".compareForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Calling compare endpoint");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/compare",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        product_url: $(".inputClass").val(),
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        if (data.amazonProducts === null) {
          $(".result-recommendation").html("Sorry, we could not find any comparable products to this.");
        } else {
          if (window.location.href !== "./result.html") {
            window.location.href = "./result.html";
          }        
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, statusText) {
        console.log("There was an erorr");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-search">
    <form class="compareForm">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="border">
          <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="" placeholder="Paste the product URL here">
        </div>
        <button type="submit"> <span>Search</span><img src="./assets/images/icon-search.png" alt="Cartaygo"></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thus, it will redirect the page when it detects that the incoming data is not "`null`" and the page where the user is located is not "`.result.html`".

---

> A little fix "`location.href`" never gives a relative link. So trying to sync with "`./result.html`" in this case will always return false. I assume you know this part and don't use relative path.

Answer (score 0):

This logic works just fine. The issue is the check in the function

```
if (window.location.href !== "./result.html") {
          window.location.href = "./result.html";
        }
```

was always failing and as a result caused the refresh every time.